# Make an automatic git branch prefix on GitHub

Tags: git, github

How can I add a prefix to the branch names in GitHub that is added automatically?

I want to be added automatically to the branch name when I'm making a branch on the GitHub repo.

for example, the prefix of the first branch is IT-1- and the second branch will be IT-2-, and so on. The number is increased automatically.
Now if I want a branch with the name checkout-improvements it will be IT-1-checkout-improvements.

I saw these kind of prefixes on bitbucket but not sure how to add it in github.